# Pandas.read_excel: Blanks in string columns convert to floats, converting via str() produces string 'Nan'

Tags: python, pandas, nan

In importing an excel file via read_excel, string columns containing blanks are read in as float. When I force them back to strings via str(), the blanks become the string 'Nan', such that when I specify df[df.column=='Nan'], the values are returned.

How can I revise my code to ensure that blanks within a column do not force the entire column to float, and that blanks in a string column are read in as ''?

Comment: you can replace the `Nan` with `''`

Comment: but what if the string could actually be Nan? Example: last name column; last name is Nan.

Comment: provide a sample data in your question

Comment: Try: `df = pd.read_excel(...).fillna('')`

Comment: @James that worked perfectly. Push it to an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Done...thanks for reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try filling NA values on read:

```
df = pd.read_excel(...).fillna('')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to convert to string. You can actually do a:

```
df[df.colname!=df.colname] #Returns True if it encounters a NaN
```